Tendency of friction to make a body purely roll
After going through this
Why does a smooth rolling ball roll indefinitely despite there being static friction?
I have concluded that friction always tries to bring the body into the state of pure rolling.
Am I right in saying so?

With no other weirdness, yes.

can you rewrite this question without personifying friction?

Like in the same way that gravity always brings you down ...
